# What is this blue bubble above my head in Zenonia?

Tags: zenonia

I'm playing Zenonia for the iPhone, and I'm in the snow levels. My character has a weird blue bubble floating above his head. Sometimes it's solid blue, other times it's white with a blue symbol inside of it. It's always sparkling and has a little sparkling chain that connects it to my character.

Normally I would assume this is some sort of status effect, perhaps due to the cold. But I can't figure out what status it actually is. Also, nothing I do makes it go away. It also doesn't seem to actually be hurting me in any way.

[image: White with blue bits in it]

[image: Solid blue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a fairy that's part of the storyline and follows you around. If you are on the "good side", the fairy is blue, and if you're on the "bad side", the fairy is red. According to Zenonia's [trailer video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BrsYbeVV0wM), their names are Langue and Parole respectively. (Also, in the final scene of the video you can see the character chose the "evil path" and has Parole floating above his head.)

Comment: Yeah, I see the two fairies talking sometimes. I thought that both of them were still with me because they both talk to each other. I also didn't realize they appeared on screen.